# How do you evaluate $\int e^{-7x}\cos^3(4x)\sin^2(4x)dx$?

Tags: calculus

How do you evaluate the following integral

$$\int e^{-7x}\cos^3{4x}\sin^2{4x}\,dx ?$$

Comment: I use [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+e%5E%7B-7x%7D%5Ccos%5E3%284x%29%5Csin%5E2%284x%29dx).

Comment: Extract one factor of $\cos 4x$ to attach to the differential, to serve with the substitution $u = \sin 4x$.  Write the remaining factor $\cos^2 4x$ as $(1 - \sin^2 4x)$ using the Pythagorean Identity.  Then multiply out the terms and split the integrand into two terms that may be integrated by parts.

Answer (score 2):

If you know complex analysis, the following might be helpful:

\begin{align}
\cos a &= \frac{ e^{ia} + e^{-ia} }{2} \\
\sin a &= \frac{ e^{ia} - e^{-ia} }{2i}
\end{align}

Comment: Writing the integrand in terms of a complex exponential is nice, but not a method generally included in second-semester calculus.  More's the pity...

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was a little reckless, even for me...  It doesn't work *literally* the way I suggested in my comment (forgot the substitution would have to be used in the exponential factor as well), but I believe you can do something like this:

Choose $u = e^{-7x}$ and $dv = \cos^3(4x) \sin^2(4x) dx$, so we have

$$du \  = \ -\frac{1}{7} \cdot e^{-7x}  \ dx \ \text{and} \  v \ = \ \frac{1}{4} \int \ (1 \ - \ w^2 ) \cdot \ w^2 \ dw \ = \ \frac{1}{4} \int \ w^2 \ - \ w^4 \ dw \ , $$

with $w = \sin 4x \ , \ dw = 4 \cos 4x \ dx $. Now, the $\int v \  du$ integral can be split into two separate integrations-by-parts, $\int \ e^{-7x} \sin^3(4x) \ dx$ and $\int \ e^{-7x} \sin^5(4x) \ dx$ , with the various multiplicative constants to be pulled together here and there...